# jQuery ajax get error while generating dynamic html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to show a popup window with user info when click on a link but I get an error. I read few posts related to this but could not resolve the issue. Please see the code.

I am calling ShowUserPopup from a link button in a gridview. Inside ShowUserPopup I am calling LoadUserDataTable function to load data into a dynamic html table and the table is added to a div, but I get an error (I think in the below line ). the service gets executed because it hits the breakpoint

```
success: function (data) {
```

Here is the code

```
function ShowUserPopup(UID) {
    //$("#divDetails").html(LoadUserDataTable());
    LoadUserDataTable();
    $("#divDetails").dialog({
        width: 600,
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide()    //Hide Title Bar

    $('#divDetails').dialog('open');
    return false;
}
function LoadUserDataTable(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../svc/SearchService.svc/GetUserProfile",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.GetUserProfileResult, function (value, key) {
                    table= $('<table></table>');
                    row = $('<tr></tr>');

                    $('<td></td>', {
                        text: 'Name'
                    }).appendTo(row);

                    $('<td></td>', {
                        text: value.FirstName + ' ' + value.LastName
                    }).appendTo(row);
                    row.appendTo(table);

                    //return table;
                    table.appendTo("#divDetails");
                    });
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
}
```

this is my link button in gridview template

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                <a id="cUser" runat="server" href="User Details" onclick ="javascript:ShowUserPopup(1);return false;"><%#Eval("User")%></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

some more error info from fiddler:

ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.Server returned 0 bytes.

Please see the service code.

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class SearchService : ISearchService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<cbEntity.User> GetUserProfile()
    {
        return new cbUserProfile(thisSession.UserId).GetUserProfile();
    }
 }   
public class cbUserProfile:User 
{
    public List<cbEntity.User> GetUserProfile()
    {
        List<cbEntity.User> lstReturn = new List<cbEntity.User>();
        Load();
        lstReturn.Add(this);
        return lstReturn;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you show your backend code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find where you returning JSON data

Comment: im sorry i dont know much about json data. i am returning a list object in the function. i am following the same method in other places too and it works fine.